# Click radio button that is not visible

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I have a radio button that has a non-visible input when inspecting element, this is what I see

[image: When hovering, nothing is shown about the code]

This is the HTML

```
<rhr-radio-button element-id="criterion-type" model="$ctrl.criterion.criterionTypeRadio" ng-value="$ctrl.CRITERION_TYPE_COST" required="true" label="procurement.evaluation.criterion.options.criterion_type_cost" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" value="COST"><!-- ngIf: $ctrl.horizontal !== 'true' && !$ctrl.readOnly --><div class="radio ng-scope" ng-if="$ctrl.horizontal !== 'true' &amp;&amp; !$ctrl.readOnly"><label><input type="radio" class="px ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" name="criterion-type" ng-value="::$ctrl.value" ng-model="$ctrl.model" ng-required="$ctrl.innerRequired" ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()" value="COST" required="required"> <span class="lbl ng-binding" ng-bind="::($ctrl.label | translate) + '&nbsp;'">Price&nbsp;</span><!-- ngIf: $ctrl.showHelpText === 'true' --></label></div><!-- end ngIf: $ctrl.horizontal !== 'true' && !$ctrl.readOnly --><!-- ngIf: $ctrl.horizontal === 'true' && !$ctrl.readOnly --><!-- ngIf: $ctrl.readOnly && $ctrl.value == $ctrl.model --></rhr-radio-button>
```

I've tried everything, such as:

```
         await element.all(by.repeater("ng-scope")).all(by.css("input[type='radio']")).get(0).click();

      all(by.tagName('radio.ng-scope')).get(0).click();

       element(by.element-id('rhr-radio-button[element-id=criterion-type]')).click();
```

I'm suspecting it has something to do with the fact that I can't see the element when inspecting. Any ideas?

Comment: The point of E2E tests is to act like a real human would. As long as you can't click on radio button using UI it is not possible to do it via protractor as well and this does make sense. Probably the problem not in that protractor can't click the hidden button, but in the whole approach you chose.

Comment: The Angular tag is wrong I have replaced it in my edit with AngularJS tag.

Comment: I can click on the radio button from the UI, the purpose of this image with inspect open is to show that I can't see the button when inspecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath.

```
 element(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-8']//input[@value='COST' and @type='radio']")).click();
```

Comment: Your's seems interesting, I had to change it a bit, because it gave me a Typescript error, what I did was   `await element(by.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-8']//input[@value='COST'] and input[type='radio']")).click(); ` and it gave me the following error: InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class='col-sm-8']//input[@value='COST'] and input[type='radio'] because of the following error:
       TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':

Comment: This seems to work, but I get an error "element not interactable", just as I suspected with not seeing the element when inspecting.. Any ideas for elements that are not interactable?

Comment: you can try the javascript to simulate the click().

Comment: OK, thanks! Since yours pretty much solved my problem, I will give it thumbs up and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if making an unclickable (by the UI) radio button is a good thing, but you could click it using jQuery in your component.ts. 
For example, you could assing an ID like 'radioButton', then just add

> $('#radioButton').click()

on your `ngOnInit()`. The button will be clicked as if it was clicked by a user.

Comment: I think this is AngularJS and not Angular.